# List directories that begin with a pattern

Tags: r, directory, file-manipulation

I have a directory with thousands of sub-directories.

Each subdirectory begins with a URL name, for example: `/australia.gov.au_about-australia`

I want to get a list of all the sub-directories that begin with a certain string, e.g. "australia.gov.au".

It appears that the `list.dirs` function does not allow for pattern matching?

I have tried the following, to no avail:

```
testSite <- "australia.gov.au"
list.files(paste0("main-directory/",paste0("^[",testSite,"]")), 
    full.names = TRUE, recursive=TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)`
```

Comment: you could just use system commands `system('cd && ls | grep "^D.*"')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Filter` to filter your directory list

```
testSite <- "australia.gov.au"
Filter(function(x) grepl(paste0("^", gsub(".", "\\.", testSite, fixed=TRUE)), x),
    list.dirs())
```

We do some extra work to convert your URL to a regular expression to do the matching.

Comment: doesn't `fixed=TRUE` belong outside some of the parentheses?

Comment: @BenBolker you need `fixed=T` in the `gsub` other wise `"."` matches every character: `gsub(".", "\\.", "hello")` returns `"....."`

Comment: OK, thanks for correcting.  (Would `gsub("\\.","\\.",...)` also be correct even though it looks weird?)

Comment: @BenBolker Actually I think it would need to be `gsub("\\.","\\\\.","ok.edu")` which looks even weirder.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. The community on this site is just amazing. I also want to note for future readers that I needed to prepend "./" for it to work properly on my Mac. So `testSite <- "./australia.gov.au"`

Answer (score 1):

Following @MrFlick's answer for the first part, but simplifying the rest slightly:

```
 re <- paste0("^", gsub(".", "\\.", testSite, fixed=TRUE))
 grep(re,list.dirs(),value=TRUE)
```